# heroku: TZ var not working after setting it to NY time

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

I'm setting heroku's timezone to **America/New_York** like so:.

```
 heroku config:add TZ="America/New_York" -a my-app
```

For some reason, the server keeps showing the logs in UTC time. Shouldn't it show them in ET ?

Log example

```
2018-12-18T01:40:06.064765+00:00
```

Comment: I can find a lot of blog posts talking about a `TZ` environment variable, but nothing in Heroku's official documentation. I'm not convinced that that variable does anything.

Comment: Thanks for your replay @Chris. Me neither. I'm a lil trapped. I guess I'll have to find another fix

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What problem are you trying to solve by setting `TZ` to `America/New_York`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53772919/cant-display-new-york-time-on-x-axis-d3-angular-nvd3 trying to solve this issue

Comment: Okay, this _definitely_ looks like an XY problem. Your server's time zone shouldn't have any impact on the time zone you show users in a front-end application.